# jquery hover - change background

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a drop-down sub-menu that toggles nicely.

When in it's loaded state 'nav ul li a' has a background image of 'arrow-r.png'
When hovered and the submenu shows, I would like the background image ot instead show 'arrow.png'

I enclose the HTML, the relevant CSS and the jquery.

And for bonus points is there any way the background image can rotate from one state to the the next?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="level0">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul">
                <li><a href="#">Account Details</a>
                <li><a href="#">Packages</a>
                <li><a href="#">Reference</a>
                <li><a href="#">Information</a>
                <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul.level0 a {
background-image:url('images/arrow-r.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And finally (and where I suspect the issue to be - jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('nav li').hover(function () {
        $('nav ul.level0 > li > a').css('background-image','url(images/arrow.png');
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to add callback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you posted code wrong, or maybe the code posted is actually identical with yours and you're missing the class attribute...

```
<nav>
    <ul class="level0">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Account Details</a>
                <li><a href="#">Packages</a>
                <li><a href="#">Reference</a>
                <li><a href="#">Information</a>
                <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul.level0 > li > a {
    background-image:url('images/arrow.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
nav ul.level0 > li > a:hover {
    background-image:url('images/arrow-r.png');
}
nav ul.level0 ul a {
    background-image:url('images/XXXX.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did copy wrong code... have edited now - also the class is a couple of levels up - see code at top.

Answer (score 0):

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

**your code**

```
$(function () {
    $('nav li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
    $('nav li').hover(function () {
        $('nav ul.level0 > li > a').css('background-image','url(images/arrow.png');
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(200);
    },function(){

    });
});
```

also add class to your `ul`

```
<ul class="level0">
```